# How to delete record from proxy table(toxi solution)?

Tags: database, laravel

There are next tables `images, posts, users, images_posts, images_users`. When I want to delete images, I send `id` of image to server, I can't delete image record, because I also have to delete record from proxy table. How to find out record from which proxy table should be deleted?

Comment: `images_posts, images_posts`, these two are proxy tables because they are the intermediate tables of two models in a many-to-many relationship

Comment: @Aless55 I have updated tables in question

Comment: They are more commonly called `pivot tables`, proxy implies something else in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a feature of the database called [cascade delete](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/). This will make sure related records also get deleted when you try to delete a record from the "main" table.

Comment: i know it, for this approach i have to delete record from ```images_posts``` table, but i am deleting record from ```images```

Comment: @DanabekDuisekov If you design your database right and your code, there shouldn't be need to execute multiple delete statements. Future you will thank you for fixing this now.